# Can not convert value of type string to expected argument type int in swift2

Tags: xml, web-services, post, soap, swift2

First I should say that I'm new to swift. 
I used `SOAPENGINE` to send post requests to Web services and then parse the response 
I'me putting response in Dictionary type variable and then I need it's elements or values to show in table view ,but I can't figure out what this error means and how should I fix it!

here is my code :

```
    struct navalist {
        //    var bullet : String!
        var Ntitle : String!
        var Speaker : String!
    }

    var tableData = [navalist]()



    var soap = [SOAPEngine]()
    var verses:NSArray = [NSArray]()

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let soap = SOAPEngine()
        soap.userAgent = "SOAPEngine"
        soap.actionNamespaceSlash = true
        soap.licenseKey = "eJJDzkPK9Xx+p5cOH7w0Q+AvPdgK1fzWWuUpMaYCq3r1mwf36Ocw6dn0+CLjRaOiSjfXaFQBWMi+TxCpxVF/FA=="
        //soap.responseHeader = true // use only for non standard MS-SOAP service

        soap.setValue("Genesis", forKey: "BookName")
        soap.setIntegerValue(1, forKey: "chapter")
        soap.requestURL("http://test.com/tv/soapServices.php",
            soapAction: "http://test.com/tv/soapServices.php/getSounds",
            completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int, dict : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in

                var book:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
//                print(book)
//                print(book["Title"])
                let soundfile : String = (book["SoundPath"] as? String)!
                let Title : String = (book["Title"] as? String)!
                let ap = navalist(Ntitle: Title, Speaker : soundfile)
                self.tableData.append(ap)
```

Comment: Please copy your code into the post directly, it's hard to see the highlighted lines on a screenshot.

Comment: @TahTatsumoto I've updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initiate your variables into NSArray and then you are able to use them as string in your tableview :

```
 var SoundTitle:NSArray = [NSArray]()
 var soundfile:NSArray = [NSArray]()

 var book:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
 let soundfile : NSArray = book["SoundPath"] as! NSArray
 let SoundTitle : NSArray = book["Title"] as! NSArray

 self.soundfile = soundfile
 self.SoundTitle = SoundTitle
 self.table.reloadData()
```